# Count number of different rows in which each word appears

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a Pandas DataFrame (or a Series, given that I'm just using one column) that contains strings. I also have a list of words. For each word in this list, I want to check how many different rows it appears in at least once. For example:

```
words = ['hi', 'bye', 'foo', 'bar']
df = pd.Series(["hi hi hi bye foo",
                "bye bye bye bye",
                "bar foo hi bar",
                "hi bye foo bar"])
```

In this case, the output should be

```
0   hi      3
1   bye     3
2   foo     3
3   bar     2
```

Because "hi" appears in three different rows (1st, 3rd and 4th), "bar" appears in two (3rd and 4th), and so on.

I came up with the following way to do this:

```
word_appearances = {}
for word in words:
    appearances = df.str.count(word).clip(upper=1).sum()
    word_appearances.update({word: appearances})

pd.DataFrame(word_appearances.items())
```

This works fine, but the problem is that I have a rather long list of words (around 40,000), around 30,000 rows to check and strings that are not as short as the ones I used in the example. When I try my approach with my real data, it takes forever to run. Is there a way to do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: I was about to post a similar solution.

Comment: You don't need 'update' method. simply 'word_appearances[word] = appearances' would work.

Comment: [Parallelize](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) the for-loop?

Comment: If you only need a count of the rows, not a count of the times each word appears, `df.str.contains('hi').sum()` might reduce the time somewhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try list comprehension and `str.contains` and `sum`

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([[word, sum(df.str.contains(word))] for word in words], 
                       columns=['word', 'word_count'])

Out[58]:
  word  word_count
0   hi           3
1  bye           3
2  foo           3
3  bar           2
```

Comment: Nice solution! I was working on using `df...sum()` instead of sum(df...)` but your method runs in roughly half the time

Comment: @G.Anderson Isn't `df.str.contains(word).sum()` faster than `sum(df.str.contains(word))`? I think the former works better in this case because it is a Pandas Series, while the second approach would work better with Python native lists. Isn't this so?

Comment: @Tendero Surprised me too, but in my testing it was `.sum()` : 1.01 ms, `sum(...)` : 527 µs. Of course, that may or may not scale well, this was tested using the `timeit` magic in jupyter on _only_ the sample data provided

Answer (score 0):

```
word_appearances = {}
for word in words:
    appearances = df.str.count(word).clip(upper=1).sum()
    word_appearances[word]= appearances

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(word_appearances,columns=['Frequency'],orient='index')
```